# How to play mp3 at specific point over waveform?

Tags: c#, winforms, mp3, naudio, waveform

I have generated waveform using [How to render audio waveform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451707/how-to-render-audio-waveform) answer from Illaya and displayed on picturebox, now i want to play sound at specific point (mark on waveform), i have used NAudio for waveform.

Screenshot can explain all things:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main idea to play from that point is you should know the seconds or milliseconds value for that point. For example I use media player control to play a file and this way, I make the player to play from second 100:

```
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "path to my file";
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 100;
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: thanks for edit question and quick answer, but for bars(lines to play) which control should i use, because user can able to move that bars on the waveform

Comment: @SunilDabhi You are welcome. I think there are different ways to do it, for example you can create your custom control and handle that lines or you can uses `TrackBar` to handle it.

Comment: thanks its helpfull for me i will try and let you know

Comment: @SunilDabhi But since the post answers your question about **How to play mp3 at specific point over waveform?** I think if my comment is not enough for you about how to use such handles, it's better to ask a new question about doing such job and keep this question clean and specific.